# MySQL: Select column name where value = something

Tags: mysql

0
gravatar for CikAlal
just now by
CikAlal • 50
Malaysia

Hi,

I have this table 'main'

```
id name courseA courseB courseC
1 Anna yes no yes
2 Mary no yes yes
3 John yes no no
4 Robb yes yes yes
```

So, I want to get column names if the search meets my requirement.
Example: Get me the column name of those courses which Anna joined.

So it will get the result the column name for `name=Anna AND 'column name'=yes`

Expected result:

```
courseA courseC
```

Anyone?

Comment: First grab the column names of the table and get result for name=Anna, then loop through all the column names to check whether is't yes or no.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change your database schema or the output you need to get, then something like this might be what you want:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    IF courseA='yes' THEN 'courseA ' ELSE '' END IF,
    IF courseB='yes' THEN 'courseB ' ELSE '' END IF,
    IF courseC='yes' THEN 'courseC ' ELSE '' END IF)
FROM table
WHERE name='Anna'
```